# Translation Golf XXXVIII - The path of the righteous man

Tags: translation-golf

> This game has ended! The winner is walen with [a 106-character translation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25824/12637). VeAqui had a [translation also with 106 characters](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25850/12637) but they had a small error in the translation: it should be "ay del que joda *a* mi gente", as the direct object of a sentence must be preceded by an "a" if it is a mention to a known collective or group of people ("mi gente" was previously referenced as "those who guide their brothers"). Examples: "dispersaron *a* la multitud", "echaron *a* la gente".

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

Following on some previous editions about great movie monologues, let's play this time with the famous "Ezekiel 25:17" speech from Samuel L. Jackson's character in *Pulp Fiction*.

> The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the inequities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of darkness, for he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who attempt to poison and destroy my brothers. And you will know my name is the Lord when I lay my vengeance upon you.
>
> <sub>(387 characters)</sub>

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here you have as a starting point the official translation as it appears in the European Spanish version of the movie:

> El camino del hombre recto está por todos lados rodeado por la avaricia de los egoístas y la tiranía de los hombres malos. Bendito sea aquel pastor que, en nombre de la caridad y de la buena voluntad, saque a los débiles del Valle de la Oscuridad. Porque él es el verdadero guardián de su hermano y el descubridor de los niños perdidos. ¡Y os aseguro que vendré a castigar con gran venganza y furiosa cólera a aquellos que pretendan envenenar y destruir a mis hermanos! ¡Y tú sabrás que mi nombre es Yavé, cuando mi venganza caiga sobre ti!
>
>  <sub>(431 characters)</sub>

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: @walen no tiene por qué, ¿no? Creo que "thou/thee" era la forma coloquial de "you", pero ambos se usaban para el singular.

Comment: _Joer_ cómo se te ha ocurrido poner este? Lo digo porque era el siguiente en mi lista para proponer si nadie se adelantaba... Qué casualidad!

Comment: @Diego busqué en Google "famous movie monologues" y en el primer resultado este aparecía el primero. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### <s>111 108</s> 106

> El justo va entre gente vil. Quien por amor guía al débil por negro val es buen tío. Y al que lo toque lo reviento, y sabréis que soy Dios.

Comment: Cosas a clarificar o corregir: el texto original ya habla de "evil men" en general y de los "selfish" en particular. Tú solo de la "mala gente". El original habla de "blessed" y "he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children", tú solo de "es buen tío". Hay muchos detalles que se han perdido por una excesiva reducción, que me gustaría ver reflejados en las traducciones.

Comment: Por otro lado, lo de "y al que lo toque lo reviento" ha hecho que la gente me mire raro en el trabajo de lo que me he reído. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## 186 caracteres

> Avaros y crueles escoltan al hombre bueno. Quien, por piedad, ayude a los flojos, ¡bravo! Guarda a los suyos y salva necesitados. Sabed que penaréis grandemente aquellos que queréis el mal para los míos, notando mi nombre en la multa.

Answer (score 3):

**106 Chars**

> El man bien cruza por viles. Gloria al que guía al pobre, pues cuida ñeros y huérfanos. ¡Ay del que joda mi gente!. Al vengarme dirán: ¡Dios!

Tomando el DAMER (modo CO), tenemos:

man: Individuo, hombre

ñero: Amigo intimo, compañero inseparable

Gloria por blessed, pobre por weak (acepción 4 o 1, la que se vea mejor), huérfanos por lost children. Ay de en términos de amenaza (2da. acepción de Ay en el DLE)

Cualquier otra explicación, me informan

Answer (score 2):

Al justo el egoísta y el tirano molestarán. Bendito es quien por caridad guía al débil en la oscuridad, cuida a sus hermanos y encuentra a los perdidos. A quien los dañe, castigaré con venganza y furia. Y sabrás que mi nombre es el Señor cuando caiga sobre tí.

#### 230

Al justo el egoísta y el tirano molestarán. Bendito es quien por caridad guía al débil en la oscuridad porque es quien cuida a sus hermanos y encuentra a los perdidos. A quien ataque a mis hermanos, castigaré con venganza y furia. Y sabrás que mi nombre es el Señor cuando me vengue de tí.

#### 355

> El camino del justo está marcado por las injusticias de los egoístas y la tiranía de los malvados. Bendito es quien en nombre de la caridad y del bien guía al débil por el valle de las sombras porque es el verdadero cuidador de sus hermanos y quien encuentra a niños perdidos. Y castigaré con gran venganza y furia a quienes intenten envenenar y destruir a mis hermanos. Y sabrás que mi nombre es el Señor, cuando lance mi venganza sobre ti.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al translation-golf! Ten en cuenta que estas preguntas no piden realmente una traducción, de hecho yo ya propongo una en la propia pregunta. De lo que se trata es de ver quién hace la traducción más corta (en número de caracteres) manteniendo toda la esencia del texto original. ¿Te animas a ver cómo puedes acortar la tuya?

Comment: ¡Bien! Ya has hecho una primera reducción. El siguiente paso sería buscar sinónimos más cortos de las palabras usadas, y comprobar si hay partes redundantes. Ejemplo: hablas de "venganza" dos veces, seguro que se puede sacar factor común. Y si ves otras respuestas, algunos han considerado que a un "guía" o "pastor" se le suponen las tareas de cuidar del rebaño (sus hermanos) y encontrar a las ovejas descarriadas (los perdidos), por lo que han omitido esas partes. ¿Te animas a continuar?